# Feeding an Akka stream sink into an akka stream source

Tags: scala, stream, akka, reactive

I have a web socket feeding into a sink of type Sink[T, NotUsed], which I need to feed into a source of type Source[T, NotUsed]. The idea is that I'm connecting over a websocket to some source and streaming the data received on this sink over rpc through the source.

i.e. web socket -> sink[T, NotUsed] -> source[T, NotUsed].

Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: not sure there's a problem, just asking how this is done :)

Answer (score 0):

you could have a look into

`Flow.fromSinkAndSource(...)`

https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Flow/fromSinkAndSource.html.

Comment: I don't think that's what this is doing. There's actually an example of what I want here: https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/24853 but I'm not sure how to work with it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `Sink.asPublisher[Message](fanout = false)` and then using `Source.fromPublisher(publisher)`?